# What JavaScript libraries are known to use the global dollar sign: window.$?

Tags: javascript

Which JavaScript libraries take over the `$` variable in the global scope?

If the library provides a different name on the global namespace, or provides a method to relinquish `window.$`, could you link to the proper function in their documentation any maybe a little code example of its use?

Having such a list could be useful in debugging potential conflicts with each other very quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scanning [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks), the only ones that come to mind are:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - Provides [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) to release the `$`
- [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar)

Comment: MooTools also has [`$`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar) too. If another library on the same page already uses `$`, MooTools will not overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Also zepto: http://zeptojs.com/

zepto actually matches most of the jQuery API.