# Which Javascript library other than jQuery uses $?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

`$ is not a function` is a common error message newbies encounter when trying to use JQuery  in Drupal 7.

The explanation is that the usage of $ is disabled in Drupal to avoid conflicts with other libraries. But which other library is using $?

Comment: dupe: [What JavaScript libraries are known to use the global dollar sign: window.$?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least two major ones:

- [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn),
- [Mootools](http://mootools.net/blog/2010/06/10/setting-up-elements/),

It is probably because using one char for most commonly used function saves a lot of time. And [due to some restrictions for characters in variable name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/548696) there are actually two candidates for such one-char names: `$` and `_` (`_` is used often for eg. gettext functions or throw-away variables). Thus I would rather expect that if some framework has some shortcut function with one char name, it is probably `$`.

Comment: Also, using one char for a global method makes your script more compact, it's not just a question of time.

Answer (score 2):

One of the common problems is several different versions of JQuery itself, though I'm not sure that is the reason in Drupal. 
Another possibility is [Mootools](http://mootools.net/)

Comment: Drupal says it is to avoid conflict between JS libraries themselves.

Comment: I meant that although it sounds like they mean different libraries, the same would be true for different versions of JQuery itself. So while a valid reason, I suspect that wasn't the primary goal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

zepto also uses $, and is a lightweight alternative to jQuery:

http://zeptojs.com/

In addition, it matches most of the jQuery API.