# Why not always use the "jQuery" function rather than "$" to avoid problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that the dollar sign is only a single character to type, and "jQuery" is 6...but doesn't simply always using the jQuery function prevent all sorts of weird problems that can occur with overloading the $ function?

If the JavaScript is obfuscated it won't matter which form is used anyway during run-time.

I'm confused why it's not a best practice to avoid $ (and treat it kind of like a JavaScript "bad part").

Comment: Convenience...that's it. Also, off topic

Comment: isn't code maintaince also important? Other libraries also use the dollar sign and jQuery even has a "no conflict" mode for this situation. Isn't "jQuery" trivial to type?

Comment: What can I say? Laziness, perhaps?

Comment: Why is this off topic anyway?

Comment: The "off-topic" voting reason is 100% for _"primarily opinion based"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard that you asked the question about `jQuery` and `$`. I (and i'm pretty sure also other developers) count it as good practice to define the name by all used external library explicitly.

Either using IIFE, ADM loaders (like requirejs)  or similar techniques, no matter how all have in common that the content of the js file is wrapped into a function body that creates a scope encapsulating all the variable and function definitions you have there and pass the used libraries as arguments to that wrapper function.

3rd party libraries that are not passed to that wrapper as parameters have to be count as not existing.

So inside of your wrapper you can use what ever name you want for the given libraries (Never the less you should stay with the common naming used by other developers)

Answer (score 0):

There’s no “overloading” involved; `$` is just another name for a function. jQuery aims to be ubiquitous within its applications, so it settled on a convenient but unlikely-to-be-taken short name. It’s also possible to guarantee its existence with an IIFE:

```
(function ($) {
    // Use $ all you want here; you know it’s the same as what jQuery pointed to
})(jQuery);
```

Frankly, jQuery’s name is one of the best things about it. If you want to be concerned about bad practice, think about how `$('#error-message').text('Really important thing!')` can fail without doing anything or even raising an error, just because you got the ID wrong by a hyphen.

Comment: "convienient but unlikely-to-be taken short name"...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window . Prototype and Mootools are pretty common...

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: jQuery is much, much, much more common. Also, Prototype and Mootools suck, and why would you use all of them at once?

Comment: "Prototype and Mootools suck" is a rather short-sighted attitude towards having the peace of mind that your code isn't trampling on other namespaces.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: See IIFE above, and also immediately following statement that you would be unlikely to use all three at once, since they do more or less the same thing, and if you did, you would indeed use them by name. (And I already have peace of mind by not using jQuery; see final paragraph.)

Comment: @false At the moment jQuery might be more common. But writing code just for the moment not thinking about maintainability is a bad thing. Using adm like loader or IIFE should always be preferred, even if it is just for the case that there might be a situation where another library is used in parallel, e.g. cause of migration or any other reason.

Comment: @t.niese: Seeing as none of jQuery, Prototype, and Mootools is compatible, if you were moving from jQuery to something else, you could easily keep `$` for jQuery and move to `$M` for Mootools, with or without an IIFE.

Comment: @t.niese: And although it isn’t really part of your point, if Prototype or Mootools ever becomes more popular than jQuery, I will give up and quit JavaScript altogether. Things are insane enough.

Comment: Using $ sounds like it adds a certain amount of technical debt. I don't want to have to remember which library I am using $ for.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: If there’s any confusion over which library `$` is in a given project, 1) by all means, please use full names; 2) something is wrong; 3) I never want to be in this project. (Again, though, my recommendation is against using any of these three – or Dojo, for that matter – and opting instead for the standard, recognizable, descriptive, and robust methods that the JavaScript DOM API provides, using polyfills and dropping IE8 JavaScript support as appropriate.)