# Attempting to implement JSFiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to recreate a JSFiddle example that converted a dropdown menu into a radio button. Here is the link that I'm referring to:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/a31p2371/16/)

After creating an HTML file, I embed the CSS and Javascript in the header of the html document. After that I went to see if it worked and it appears to have not.  Here is the code that I currently have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
  /* http://jsfiddle.net/496c9/ */
 .radioSelectContainer > select {
     /*display: none;*/
}
.radioSelectContainer > label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > span {
    padding:0.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
</style>
<script>
  $(function () {

  $('.radioSelect').each(function (selectIndex, selectElement) {

    var select = $(selectElement);
    var container = $("<div class='radioSelectContainer' />");
    select.parent().append(container);
    container.append(select);

    select.find('option').each(function (optionIndex, optionElement) {
      var radioGroup = select.attr('id') + "Group";
      var label = $("<label />");
      container.append(label);

      $("<input type='radio' name='" + radioGroup + "' />")
          .attr("value", $(this).val())
          //.click((function () { select.val($(this).val()); })) //radio updates select - see optional below
          .appendTo(label);

      $("<span>" + $(this).val() + "</span>").appendTo(label);
    });

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click
    //optional - this logic handles unchecking when clicking on an already checked radio
    container.find(":radio + span").mousedown(
      function (e) {
        var $span = $(this);
        var $radio = $($span.prev());
        if ($radio.is(':checked')) {
          var uncheck = function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $radio.prop('checked', false); }, 0);
          };
          var unbind = function() {
            $span.unbind('mouseup', up);
          };
          var up = function() {
            uncheck();
            unbind();
          };
          $span.bind('mouseup', up);
          $span.one('mouseout', unbind);
        } else {
          select.val($radio.val());
        }
      }
    );

    select.change((function () { //select updates radio
      $("input[name='" + select.attr('id') + "Group" + "'][value='" + this.value + "']").prop("checked", true);
    }));
  });
}); 

  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="radioSelect" id="sizeOptions">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
    <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
    <option value="3XL">3XL</option>
    <option value="4XL">4XL</option>
    <option value="5XL">5XL</option>
</select>
     
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add jquery library to your head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>` before any `<script>` tag that uses the variable called `$`.

This code snippet will allow you to use `$` (which is used for jQuery in your code sample)!

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Note that `$` is not necessarily a synonym for jQuery! jQuery uses it as its own shortcut, that's true, but others like Prototype and Mootools also do this. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window).)