# Where is the definition of selector ' $' in JS library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-development-server

Which library of JavaScript having definition of selector '$' ?
How it becomes globally accessible ???
Can we write a new operator  ?

Comment: Jquery is the library which has $ selector.

Comment: Yes, you can define `$` as a variable.

Comment: You need to add the CDN link in your html file to make it globally available

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I am asking the name of the library ? How can we define other variables so that they will be globally accessible like '$' !!  @VaibhavSingh

Comment: @VaibhavSingh `$` is not a selector

Comment: if iam not wrong, you want to change $ sign to some other sign ? 
use $.noConflict() 

read more -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: The dollar sign `$` has no special meaning in JS, it is simply one of various characters that may be used in variable names. [Several popular libraries declare a function with the name `$`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window). It becomes globally accessible the same way a function with any other name does.

Comment: No, First of all i want to know where '$' define ?
What makes it globally accessible ?
Can we define some new operators like this "Globally accessible" if yes then how ?

Comment: *"where '$' define"* - Download and open jquery.js, and search through the code for `window.$`.

Comment: '$' is defined in the jquery library @dineshkandpal

Comment: If you want to define "$" like global variables, you can do this 

window.var_name='something'

Comment: *"Can we define some new operators like this"* - **It is *not* an operator**, it is a function name. Operators are things like `+`, `-`, `&&`, etc. You cannot define new operators, but you can define as many functions as you like.

Comment: I think we wants to define global variable like '$' is for jquery.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a valid variable name in JavaScript. So you free to write something like

```
var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
var elements = $('a.link');
```

In practice, `$` is an alias of a `jQuery` function from the corresponding library.

Comment: jQuery or Mootools it is,  and will conflict with eachother which can be fixed by f.e.: `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: @artptr  I want to ask Can we define our own variable that represent whole library ? as $ represent can we override existing $ sign with our our sign as ^,# ?

Comment: @dineshkandpal You can't. Only $ and _ chars may be present in a variable name. So $ widely associated with jQuery, while _ is associated with Underscore or Lodash. But you still can use them for your own purposes.